# Bash: Rounding up unix time to the nearest minute in human readable format

Tags: linux, bash, date, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have a list of epoch timestamps like the following:

1481842799,1481842859,.....

So far I managed to use the date command to convert this time in human readable format as follows:

```
date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' -d @1481842799
20161215235959

date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' -d @1481842859
20161216000059
```

or

```
date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' --date='@1481842799'
20161215235959
```

How can I use the date command to round up such time to the nearest minute as follows?:

20161215235959 to 20161216000000, 20161216000059 to 20161216000100

Tried the following but does not work:

```
date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' --date='@1481842799 + 1 seconds'
date: invalid date `@1481842799 + 1 seconds'
```

Comment: Do you know that all the timestamps correspond to times with 59 seconds, so that rounding is as simple as adding one second? (Exception: do you need to account for leap seconds?) Or could the second field have an arbitrary value and you need to actually round up to the next minute?

Comment: I tried to add 1 second but as you can see I could not do it with the date command.

Comment: Would be nice to also know how to round up when I have an arbitrary second. Not sure if the date command supports such functionality.

Comment: @Inian, yes it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `GNU date`, quite evident from the `-d` flag. If your intention is to increment one second to the `EPOCH` time, do it as below using the `bash` arithmetic operator `$(())`

```
date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' -d "@$((1481842799 + 1))"
20161216043000
```

Even without incrementing, you can use the double-quotes as

```
date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' -d "@$((1481842799))"
20161216042959
```

which is pretty much the same as

```
date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' -d @1481842799
20161216042959
```

As an alternate suggestion, to round up to the nearest minute, you are better off adding 59 and then dividing and multiplying by 60 to truncate that *down* to the nearest minute, somewhat like [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s suggestion in the comments.

```
date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' -d "@$(( ((1481842799 + 59) / 60) * 60))"
20161216043000
```

Adding 59 instead of 60 means that when the original value is already a multiple of 60, it will not be rounded up.